# XML to JSON with XSD scheme

Tags: java, json, xml, xsd

Is any Java open source library for conversion XML to JSON with usage of XSD scheme? I tried to use [org.json](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json) and  [com.fasterxml.jackson](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core) and both don't support this functionality.

Comment: I don't know of any. But requests for finding a library are off-topic for StackOverflow. [Hint: you can get round this by claiming that you are trying to write the code yourself, and someone is likely to tell you that you don't need to because there's a library.]

Comment: Underscore-java library has a static method U.xmlToJson(xml).